# Colocar componente <gmap-autocomplete> de vue2-google-maps dentro del mapa

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vue2-google-map

Estoy haciendo uso del paquete ***"vue2-google-maps"*** en una aplicacion desarrollada con Laravel 5.7. En este caso estoy creando un componente con el nombre *google-map*. Dendro de este componente se utiliza **gmap-autocomplete** y **gmap-map**. El componente està registrado en *app.js* y funciona correctamente tanto el mapa como el input autocomplete.
El problema es que el input se ubica arriba del mapa y lo que deseo es que esté dentro del mapa.

Actualmente estoy logrando esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deseo que quede como la siguiente imagen:

[image: input autocomplete dentro del mapa]

Esto normalmente lo lograría(sin usar vue ni dicho paquete) con las siguientes lineas:

```
let inputSearch = document.getElementById('pac-input');
searchBoxAdd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputSearch );
myMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(searchBoxAdd );
```

Pero en este caso ya no es lo mismo. Según la documentación, vi que puedo acceder al objeto "map" agregando `ref="mapRef"` a mi componente gmap-map y agregando

```
mounted () {
    this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
      // En este punto ya tengo mi objeto map.
    })
  }
```

En base a esta información probé hacer lo siguiente:

```
mounted () {
        this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
          let inputSearch = document.getElementById('pac-input');
          searchBoxAdd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputSearch );
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(searchBoxAdd );
        })
```

Pero sigue sin cargar el input en el interior del mapa y en consola me muestra el siguiente error:

> controls.js:118 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'zIndex' of undefined

Les dejo mi componente principal, que sería "google-maps"

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>Search and add a marker</h2>
            <label>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <gmap-autocomplete
                        class="form-control"
                        @place_changed="setPlace">
                    </gmap-autocomplete>
                    <button @click="addMarker" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Add</button>
                </div>
            </label>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <gmap-map ref="mapRef"
            :center="center"
            :zoom="12"
            style="width:100%;  height: 400px;"
        >
            <gmap-marker
                :key="index"
                v-for="(m, index) in markers"
                :position="m.position"
                @click="center=m.position"
            ></gmap-marker>
        </gmap-map>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {gmapApi} from 'vue2-google-maps';

    export default {
        name: "GoogleMap",

        data() {
            return {
                // default to Montreal to keep it simple
                // change this to whatever makes sense
                center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
                markers: [],
                places: [],
                currentPlace: null
            };
        },

        mounted() {
            this.geolocate();
        },

        methods: {
            // receives a place object via the autocomplete component
            setPlace(place) {
                this.currentPlace = place;
            },
            addMarker() {
                if (this.currentPlace) {
                    const marker = {
                        lat: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lat(),
                        lng: this.currentPlace.geometry.location.lng()
                    };
                    this.markers.push({ position: marker });
                    this.places.push(this.currentPlace);
                    this.center = marker;
                    this.currentPlace = null;
                }
            },
            geolocate: function() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    this.center = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya logré solucionarlo, lo hice con los siguientes pasos:

1. Agregar `ref="mapRef"` a la etiqueta *gmap-map*. Con esto mas adelante podré tener acceso al objeto "map". La etiqueta debe quedar así:

   ```
   <gmap-map ref="mapRef"
   :center="center"
   :zoom="12"
   :options="mapOptions" // Para ocultar el control "mapTypeControl"
    style="width:100%;  height: 400px;"
   >
   </gmap-map>
   ```
2. Mi control queda del siguiente modo:

   ```
    <div class="hide">
      <div class="input-group col-md-6" id="myAutocomplete">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text bg-primary" id="basic-text1">
               <i class="fa fa-search text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
      </div>
      <gmap-autocomplete
          class="form-control my-0 py-1"
          @place_changed="setPlace">
      </gmap-autocomplete>
      </div>
   </div>
   ```

   El div "padre" con la clase "hide" es importante, sino el input se mostrará en la pagina antes de terminar de cargar el mapa y luego lo moverá a su interior. Con esto, cuando esta listo el mapa lo muestra en su interior directamente. El resto ya son estilos...
3. Voy a agregar una configuración extra para ocultar *mapTypeControl* .Esto **NO** es obligatorio.

   ```
     data() {
               return {
                   // default to Montreal to keep it simple
                   // change this to whatever makes sense
                   center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
                   markers: [],
                   places: [],
                   currentPlace: null,
                   mapOptions: {
                       mapTypeControl: false
                   }
               };
           },
   ```
4. Una vez que el componente esta montado, es decir en el evento "`mounted()`" voy a usar el objeto "map" para agregar mi componente. El código debe quedar así:

   ```
   mounted() {
           this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
               var myControl = document.getElementById('myAutocomplete');

               myControl.index = 1; // Esto es importante sino arroja error.

               map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(myControl);
           })
       },
   ```

Una vez hecho todo esto, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Espero que le sirva a alguien. Saludos!

Comment: Igual aquí en la documentación oficial se explica cómo hacerlo https://diegoazh.github.io/gmap-vue/examples/autocomplete.html#live-example

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#SearchBox) (y en javascript en general), al instanciar un nuevo Searchbox lo que obtienes es la instancia de la "clase" (en este caso un objeto).

Por el contrario, cuando pusheas algo a `map.controls[<ubicación>]` lo que espera google maps es un HTMLElement. Significa que podrías probar con:

```
let inputSearch = document.getElementById('pac-input'),
    searchBoxAdd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputSearch );

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(inputSearch);
```

Si eso no resulta, yo probaría detectar el primer evento `map_idle` antes de manipular el DOM del contenedor del mapa.

Comment: Hola @amenadiel, es exactamente lo mismo que puse arriba que probé y no funciona.  Mas allá de esto sin `searchBoxAdd = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(inputSearch );` no funcionaria el autocomplete. Ese código tal cual está funciona correctamente haciéndolo con js puro, pero en este caso con el componente no va.  Saludos!